# Google Wallet Push Notifications

Tags: firebase, api, firebase-cloud-messaging, wallet

I have integrated Google Wallet to my e-commerce store so the user can add loyalty cards and coupons to their google e-wallet . Now I need to know how can I use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) to send push notifications to the user throughout google wallet upon pass updating (like received new points , new tier , expired etc...).

I have tried to search on the internet about it but have found nothing. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you trying to send a push notification through Google Wallet or through your own app?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderN. Thanks for your reply , yes I am trying to send a push notification through Google Wallet . My E-commerce app is a web app not an android one .

Comment: FCM wouldn't be able to do that. The wallet api would control notifications for the wallet app. More documentation can be found here https://developers.google.com/wallet/retail/offers/use-cases/offer-expiration-notification#custom-offer-expiration-notification-time

Answer (score 1):

FCM wouldn't be able to do that. The wallet api would control notifications for the wallet app. More documentation can be found here: https://developers.google.com/wallet/retail/offers/use-cases/offer-expiration-notification#custom-offer-expiration-notification-time